# Django get last GET parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, get, url-parsing

I've been working with Django for a few months now so I'm still new at it.

I want to get the last GET parameter from the URL. Here is and example of the URL:

```
example.com?q=Something&filter1=Test&filter1=New&filter2=Web&filter3=Mine
```

Is there a way to get the last inserted GET parameter with django? It could be `filter1`, `filter2` or `filter3`..

Maybe there is a way to do this after the initial refresh with javascript/jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not rely on the order of the parameters; this will lead to problems later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to parse url parameters yourself. For example:

### Python/Django

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qsl

full_url = ''.join([request.path, '?', request.META['QUERY_STRING']])
#example.com?q=Something&filter1=Test&filter1=New&filter2=Web&filter3=Mine
parameters = parse_qsl(urlparse(full_url)[4])
#[(u'q', u'Something'), (u'filter1', u'Test'), (u'filter1', u'New'), (u'filter2', u'Web'), (u'filter3', u'Mine')]
last_parameter = parameters[-1]
#(u'filter3', u'Mine')
```

### Javascript

```
var params = window.location.search.split("&");
//["?q=Something", "filter1=Test", "filter1=New", "filter2=Web", "filter3=Mine"]
var last_param = params[params.length-1].replace("?","").split("=");
//["filter3", "Mine"]
```

This example do not use jQuery and provides basic knowledge of url parsing. There are a lot of libraries, that can do it for you.